# Servlet exception on local webapp

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to connect to my local webapp via **Connexion.java**. But this error figure out. How can I fix it please?

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at com.bh.servlets.Connexion.doPost(Connexion.java:28)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**ConnexionForm.java**

```
public final class ConnexionForm {
    private static final String CHAMP_LOGIN  = "login";
    private static final String CHAMP_PASS   = "mdp";

    private String              resultat;
    private Map<String, String> erreurs      = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public String getResultat() {
        return resultat;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErreurs() {
        return erreurs;
    }

    public User connecterUser( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        /* Récupération des champs du formulaire */
        String login = getValeurChamp( request, CHAMP_LOGIN );
        String mdp = getValeurChamp( request, CHAMP_PASS );

        User User = new User();

        /* Validation du champ login. */
        try {
            validationChamps( login , mdp );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            setErreur( "champs", e.getMessage() );
        }
        User.setIdentifiant( login );

        /* Initialisation du résultat global de la validation. */
        if ( erreurs.isEmpty() ) {
            resultat = "Succès de la connexion.";
        } else {
            resultat = "<br/>Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe saisi est incorrect. <br/><br/>Échec de la connexion.";
        }

        return User;
    }

    private void validationChamps( String login , String mdp) throws Exception {

            if(find(login) != null && !mdp.matches(find(login).getMdp()))
                throw new Exception( "Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe saisi est incorrect." );

    }

    public User find(String login) {
        User u = null;     

        try {
            Session s = HibernateUtils.getSession();
            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
            Query query = s.createQuery("from User where id = :y");
            query.setString("y", login);
            u = (User) query.uniqueResult();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
//          s.close();
        }
        return u;
      }

    /*
     * Ajoute un message correspondant au champ spécifié à la map des erreurs.
     */
    private void setErreur( String champ, String message ) {
        erreurs.put( champ, message );
    }

    /*
     * Méthode utilitaire qui retourne null si un champ est vide, et son contenu
     * sinon.
     */
    private static String getValeurChamp( HttpServletRequest request, String nomChamp ) {
        String valeur = request.getParameter( nomChamp );
        if ( valeur == null || valeur.trim().length() == 0 ) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return valeur;
        }
    }
}
```

**Connexion.java**

```
public class Connexion extends HttpServlet {
    public static final String ATT_USER           = "user";
    public static final String ATT_FORM           = "form";
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_USER   = "sessionUtilisateur";
    public static final String VUE                = "/WEB-INF/connexion.jsp";
    public static final String ACCUEIL            = "/WEB-INF/accueil.jsp";

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* Affichage de la page de connexion */
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );
    }

    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ConnexionForm form = new ConnexionForm();

        User user = form.connecterUser( request );

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        request.setAttribute( ATT_FORM, form );
        request.setAttribute( ATT_USER, user );

        if ( form.getErreurs().isEmpty() ) {
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, user );
            response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath() + "/accueil" );
        } else {
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, null );
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );
        }

    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Connexion</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bh.servlets.Connexion</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Connexion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/connexion</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Deconnexion</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bh.servlets.Deconnexion</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Deconnexion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/deconnexion</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Accueil</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bh.servlets.Accueil</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Accueil</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/accueil</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Operation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bh.servlets.Operation</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Operation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/afficheOperations</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bh.servlets.Upload</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>chemin</param-name> 
            <param-value>/fichiers/</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <multipart-config>
          <location>E:/fichiers</location>
          <max-file-size>485760</max-file-size>
          <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
          <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>

      </servlet-mapping>
      <filter>
            <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>ignore</param-name>
                <param-value>false</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**NOTE:** at com.bh.servlets.Connexion.doPost(Connexion.java:28) = at com.bh.servlets.Connexion.doPost(Connexion.java:14) in this **Connexion.java** class

I'm not using SPRING

Comment: the problem is explicit : java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml]

Comment: But this source code worked before, I've just changed the function find(String login) and this exception figured out.

Comment: Do you have some CXF dependencies too ?

Comment: Post your web.xml. You have something weird because YOU ARE using CXF ;) check your classpath/WEB-INF libs

Comment: Could you stop editing your question ! the stacktrace is not the same !!!

Comment: Now you miss some Hibernate dependencies : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException!

Comment: What's the utility of CXF in a Dynamic web project? Thank you very much @willome, but the problem persists :/

Comment: cxf is used for adding some Web Services (jaxws or jaxrs)

Comment: So what's wrong with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException do you think ?:/

Comment: You do need some Hiberntae dependencies (hibernate-core, hibernate-jpa-2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You do need some Hibernate dependencies (hibernate-core, hibernate-jpa-2, ...)

Comment: I don't think so, maybe the problem is in the instanciation of the ConnexionForm.java class. Look at this line **at com.bh.servlets.Connexion.doPost(Connexion.java:28)**

Comment: look at your stack trace ! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException

Comment: look here is my Hibernate lib http://www.monalbum.fr/Album=YY46ETLP
what have I to add please?

Comment: Your screenshot is missing some libs : check if you have got hibernate-core and hibernate-jpa-2. Using maven on your project would be easier to manage your libs/dependencies.

Comment: I've just added these jars, but the problem persists :'(